# Changing the font size of a RichTextBox Selection through a ComboBox doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have created a very simple WPF Window consisting of a Grid containing one `RichTextBox` and one `ComboBox`. I use the `ComboBox` for changing and looking up the font size of the `RichTextBox` selection.

Here's the code-behind file of my XAML:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Add the font sizes.
        for (var i = 1; i < 72; i++)
        {
            FontSize.Items.Add((double) i);
        }
    }

    private void MyTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the selection changes, update the font size in the ComboBox.
        FontSize.SelectedValue = (double) MyTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty);
    }

    private void FontSize_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // If the selected size changes, change the size of the selection in the RichTextBox.
        if (FontSize.SelectedItem != null)
            MyTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, FontSize.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

There are two things here:

1. `MyTextBox_SelectionChanged` updates the `ComboBox` with the font size of the selection.
2. `FontSize_SelectionChanged` changes the font size of the selection.

You can see the problem below:

[image]

When I make a selection and change the font size, it changes perfectly. But the moment I click on another text with a different font size it changes back again.

What is causing this behavior?

**Edit:** Here's the XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="FontSize" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Margin="10,10,0,0" SelectionChanged="FontSize_SelectionChanged"/>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="273" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" Margin="10,37,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.358,0.48" SelectionChanged="MyTextBox_SelectionChanged">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="RichTextBox"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Edit 2:** Here's the short explanation of what I did when I was debugging it:

1. There are two debug points, one at `MyTextBox_SelectionChanged`, and one at `FontSize_SelectionChanged`.
2. When I change the font size, I click on F5 and continue.
3. When I click on another part of the text (that has the default size), `MyTextBox_SelectionChanged` is called. The `Selection.Text` is empty.
4. Then I continue again and stop at the call to `FontSize_SelectionChanged`. But still the `Selection.Text` is empty, but my older selection "Rich" returns back to the old font size.

**Edit 3:** This problem is mentioned in [Sams Teach Yourself WPF in 24 Hours](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329859) first printing July 2008, page 135, "*Making the Text Editor Work as Expected*", item 9. I didn't understand the explanation there and created a short sample illustrating that specific problem.

Comment: The piece of code you have posted doesn't cause the problem you have mentioned (atleast on my machine). So it's some other code which is causing the problem. Also, there's a different problem with MyTextBox_SelectionChanged code. In case user selects a text which has multiple fontsizes (e.g. RichTex in your example), it throws exception.

Comment: @publicgk: There's no other code that can cause the problem. There's the `MainWindow.xaml`, which has one `ComboBox` named `FontSize` and there's one `RichTextBox` named `MyTextBox`. And what I have posted is everything there's in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file except the namespace declaration. It's unlikely that it doesn't cause any problem, because this problem was mentioned in a book that I'm reading. And I couldn't understand the explanation in the book so that's why I asked it here.

Comment: @publicgk: And the other problem that you have mentioned is not an issue, because I wrote this code specifically to mention this problem. It was not written to handle any other situation than that.

Comment: Strangely, when i copy-pasted your code and ran it i did not notice the issue you mentioned. Although i did get runtime exception. Maybe the XAML that i used might be different from yours. Can you post XAML also?

Comment: @publicgk: Just did it.

Comment: +1 for the visualization

Comment: Note for those not able to repro this, on my system it appears to depend on the direction in which you select the text! Select by dragging left to right, as the animation does, and it repros. Select the same text right to left, no repro!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that when you click to clear the selection, this causes your `TextBox.SelectionChanged` event handler (`MyTextBox_SelectionChanged`) to be invoked while the `Selection` represents an empty selection (i.e., just an insertion point). Your handler sets the combo box's `SelectedValue`, using the empty selection's font size, which is a perfectly reasonable thing to do even if the selection is empty. (The insertion point still has a font size.)

Changing the `SelectedValue` of course causes your `ComboBox.Selection` event handler (`FontSize_SelectionChanged`) to run. And because that event handler has no easy way to distinguish between an event caused by the user selecting a new value, and the event being caused by your code changing the `SelectedValue` property, it goes ahead and attempts to modify the selection's font size, which you probably don't want to be doing in this particular case.

Even so, you'd think it'd be OK, because the selection is empty, and you're just attempting to set its font size to be whatever its font size already is. But here's the weird thing: when you call `ApplyPropertyValue` on this empty selection, it appears to set the `FontSize` for the entire document.

So the effect is that when you click to clear the selection, your code sets the entire document's font size to be whatever the font size is at the point where you click.

I suspect that's a bug in `ApplyPropertyValue`, because it only happens if the text you select initially was selected by dragging from left to right, starting at the very first character. Then again, it's not entirely clear what the behaviour is meant to be if you apply formatting to an empty selection. So perhaps this is more just a case of invoking undefined behaviour rather than hitting a definite bug in WPF.

In any case, a reasonable way to fix this is by modifying your combo box change handler:

```
if (FontSize.SelectedItem != null && !MyTextBox.Selection.IsEmpty)
{
    MyTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(
        TextBlock.FontSizeProperty, FontSize.SelectedItem);
}
```

This only attempts to change the selection's font size if the selection is non-empty.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I will award the bounty when it's possible (it won't let me do it for another 15 hours). By the way, the problem occurs regardless of what direction I make the selection on my system, not just from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

When you select your Text, then change the size over the Menu, your code is still selected even though you don't see the selection anymore, now when you select your code the SelectionChanged method fires before the MyTextBoxSelection changes, ( i just guess/believe that, i think i had such a problem once). Now you change your Fontsize and the Fontsize method fires which accesses the not updated Selection, making your last change void.

Comment: But I check the `Selection` with a debug point, it looks empty. Why does it still change?